# How can I insert a customized emoticon in SMS? Galaxy S2

Tags: sms, samsung-galaxy-s-2

Just wondering if is it possible to insert a customized emoticon in SMS.
I get only those :-) default ones. I'd like to use smth like :) or :-x or 8-)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the keyboard you are using, the SMS emoticons will show up in the bottom right (where the enter key usually is). If you long press on the key, you will get a pop-up of other emoticons you can use. Using :) is the same as :-) so they wont show that one.

You can send any emoticon you want, but if who you send it to doesn't "change it" to an image, they will only see the normal "8-)" version.

[image: emoticons]

Answer (score 1):

First go to type a text, then tap the <kbd>?123</kbd> key then press the <kbd>1/3</kbd> key twice and you will be shown a page full of emotions.

Alternatively, you can download another SMS app such as [Handcent](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.handcent.nextsms&hl=en).

Answer (score 0):

An alternative keyboard like [Smart Keyboard](https://market.android.com/details?id=net.cdeguet.smartkeyboardpro&hl=en) has similar support. It also allows a user to customise which smileys are shown and to edit them. A user can also specify whether they prefer an ENTER key or a SMILEY key to be shown. Long-pressing shows a pop-up with smileys.

Note that these are punctuation marks and not images. If the user's SMS app can convert these punctuation marks into graphical image smileys, then the recipient will see those, else he/she'll see the text characters.

Answer (score 0):

You could use GO Keyboard app, instead of the stock keypad. It has an advanced setting which allows you to pick from the following styles:
:)
:-)
:^)
:o)

GO SMS Pro app is even better. It lets you display emoticons as cute images, but it's good only if the other user also has GO SMS Pro.